# One large model or two smaller models

Tags: django, database, django-models, psql

I'm developing a database that holds financial information.

I have two models:

1. Company (~30 fields)
2. CompanyFinacials (~120 fields)

CompanyFinacials includes a field with Company as a primary key to maintain the relationship.

I need to 10 add investment rounds to CompanyFinacials. Each round will have 12 fields.

So, the question is, do i build it like this:

```
class CompanyFinancials(models.Model):
    company = models.OneToOneField(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    financial_start_year = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True) ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
    
class fundingRound(models.Model):
    company_obj = models.OneToOneField(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    funding_stage = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
    target_size_of_raise = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
    invest_amount = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
    investment_vehicle = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
    discount_percent = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
    pre_money_valuation = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
    dilution = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
    post_money_valuation = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
    equity_percent = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
```

or like this:

```
class CompanyFinancials(models.Model):
    company = models.OneToOneField(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    financial_start_year = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
    ...
    ...
    ...
   round1_funding_stage = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round1_target_size_of_raise = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round1_invest_amount = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round1_investment_vehicle = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round1_discount_percent = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round1_pre_money_valuation = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round1_dilution = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round1_post_money_valuation = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round1_equity_percent = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round2_funding_stage = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round2_target_size_of_raise = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round2_invest_amount = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round2_investment_vehicle = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round2_discount_percent = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round2_pre_money_valuation = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round2_dilution = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round2_post_money_valuation = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
   round2_equity_percent = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
    ...
    ...
    ...
   round10_equity_percent = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='NONE', blank=True)
```

I can see that the DB model will very large if I manually put all 10 rounds into it, but is there really a disadvantage? It would be easier to work with an object that contains all the data.

**Should I add a separate object for fundingRound, or keep it all in the CompanyFinancials model?** And why?

Comment: 120 fields is bizarre, especially since it will have a lot of `NULL`,s but even then, it is not said that 10 rounds are enough.

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike so you're suggesting option 1 b/c it will reduce the amount of fields by 110 and reduce DB storage space when the company has a smaller amount of rounds? Is there any advantage to using 2? I agree that 1 seems like the way to go, but I have nothing to back my assumption

Comment: As WillemVO says. Don't forget to add a `round_number` to `FundingRound`, or some other means of accessing/ordering them in the order they occurred. (I'd have expected a date, but it's not in your posted code. Also put a unique constraint on the round number along with the company. Also I think its  a ForeignKey not a OneToOne (many to one, up to 10+ per company).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I add a separate object for `FundingRound`, or keep it all in the CompanyFinancials model? And why?

**Yes**. As one of my professors said: in modeling there are usually only three constants *zero*, *one* and *infinity*. The fact that you enter nine fields per round, and ten round results in 90 fields. It results in a database where querying will be cumbersome. If you want to check if any round got more than $10M in investment, that will require a query with nine `OR`s in between.

Even if that all would work, it is not said that ten round will be enough, eventually it is possible some `Company` turns up with eleven rounds, or more, so then there is no space anymore.

It will introduce a lot of `NULL`s, a lot of duplicated code to validate all these elements, and eventually make it harder.

Usually modeling is the other way around: *linearizing*. Splitting things into rows, not columns. This makes summing up funding rounds, checking the amount of funding rounds, guaranteeing data integrity a lot harder.

In fact the modeling violates the [*first normal form* of databases <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) that aims to *linearize* data. Another thing that should probably be fixed is using dedicated fields to store data, a [**`DecimalField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) for example for percentages.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Some big DB updates coming soon haha